# How to read all images in a folder efficiently?

Tags: numpy, image-processing

I have a folder. It contains approximately 30,000 images. I wish to read all these images, convert them to a 20×20×3 shape  and add them to a NumPy array. How do I do this in an efficient way without exhausting memory? Right now, I'm using a for loop to go through each image in the folder, read it with Sci-Kit Image and add it to an array. This is destroying my RAM and taking forever.

Comment: Do you read and resize them one by one, or do you first read them all in, and then resize them? 30k * 20 * 20 * 3 is only 36M, shouldn’t be a problem in memory on a modern computer.

Comment: Rather than **appending** them to a Numpy array, try creating the full-size, empty array at the outset and copying them into the correct place rather than appending.

Comment: I think your problem lies somewhere else. provide your code and an example image. follow @MarkSetchell advice. you already know the size of your final array. use that knowledge to avoid unnecessary operations.

Comment: If you haven't already, multithreading will speed it up ~*#cores